# Axios accessing wrong useState data in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

When trying to access variables to complete a patch request in axios, i receive a 200 response, however the data which is sent is the initial data from the get request, rather than the new data from the form. upon using console.log to see if the variable was updated, the new data was set to the variable, however axios still won't access the proper data.

in order to get this, i used this code:

```
import { withPageAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Image from 'next/image'
import Head from 'next/head';
import axios from 'axios'
import styles from './Edit.module.css'


export default function AddMember () {

    const [name, setName] = useState([])
    const [occupation, setOccupation] = useState('')
    const [paragraph, setParagraph] = useState('')
    const [date, setDate] = useState('')

    const router = useRouter()
    const { id }= router.query

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAbout = () => {
            axios
            .get('http://localhost:5000/members/' + id)
            .then((res) => {
                setName(res.data.name)
                setOccupation(res.data.occupation)
                setParagraph(res.data.bio)
                setDate(res.data.join)
            })
            .catch((err) =>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
        fetchAbout()
        
    }, [id])

    const handleName = ({target:{value}}) => setName(value)
    const handleOccupation = ({target:{value}}) => setOccupation(value)
    const handleParagraph = ({target:{value}}) => setParagraph(value)
    const handleDate = ({target:{value}}) => setDate(value)

    const cancelHandler = () => {
        window.location = '/members'
    }

    const [image, setImage] = useState("")
    const onImageChange = (event) => {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        setImage(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
        }
    }

    const submitHandle = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios
        .patch('http://localhost:5000/members/' + id, {
            name: name
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
        })
    }

    return(
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Member | Edit</title>
            </Head>
            <div className={styles.editMember}>
                <form onSubmit={submitHandle} encType="multipart/form-data">
                    <div className={styles.title}>
                        <div className={styles.bar}/>
                        <div className={styles.image}><Image alt='' src={image} layout='fill'/></div>
                        <input type="file" onChange={onImageChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.inputs}>
                        <div>
                            <input value={name} placeholder="Name" onChange={handleName} />
                            <input value={occupation} placeholder="Occupation" onChange={handleOccupation} />
                            <input value={date} placeholder="Member Since" onChange={handleDate} />
                        </div>
                        <textarea value={paragraph} placeholder="Paragraph" onChange={handleParagraph} />
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.buttons}>
                        <button type="submit">Add</button>
                        <button onClick={cancelHandler}>Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuthRequired();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure that the patch service returns the new object after update ?

because if you are using mongodb `Model.findOneAndUpdate`, this returns the old model before update. if this is the problem, you can add `{new: true}` to the function to return the updated object as a result

```
const updated = Model.findOneAndUpdate(
{_id:id},
{// your updated}, 
{new:true}
)
```

Comment: hi! thank you a lot for your answer. inspired by your comment i did check the api itself and found i need to specify the variables in order for them to be patched. thank you !!